# report services hidden details and not shows white space

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have this report

[image]

when you execute this see as it

[image]

But when you press on + or - this stays as it[image]

it has a ugly white space.

i would like this see as it (example on Excel)
[image]

so you could see details are hidden and there is not a white space when they are.
you could press on + and see details. now in report services when you press + or - it gets a whites spaces... what do I need configurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a regular drilldown report, if I understood you right.

In your tablix ensure you've set the visibility of the whole detailed row to 'When the report is initially run = Hide', and choose the textbox which holds the parent item (indicadornombre) as the toggle report item:

[image]

[image]